# Javascript - passing index to setInterval callback

Tags: javascript, callback

**The problem**

I'm trying to simplify a long javascript code and i have a problem with identifying callbacks.

I have a large array with elements to animate on page

```
[selector, activate interval, hide after]:

things_to_move = [
        ['.ufo, .chefoven, .sushi', 9900, 2000],
        ['.hotdog,.pizzaman,.boyballon', 12090, 3600],
        (...)
]
```

Basically, the aim is to to activate each of the selectors every x seconds, and hide them x seconds later, as per the example above.

**Current code**

After many tries, I ended up with this:

```
// Activate the element, and set timeout to hide it
var showFun = function(index1) {  
    $(things_to_move[index1][0]).addClass('move');      
    setTimeout( function(){hideFun(index1)},things_to_move[index1][2]);   
}
// Hide the element
var hideFun = function(index2) {   
     $(things_to_move[index2][0]).removeClass('move');  
} 

// Loop through all items and set the interval for each one
for(_A=0; _A < things_to_move.length; _A++) { 
    setInterval(function(){showFun(_A)}, things_to_move[_A][1]);    
}
```

But of course this doesn't work. Every time the showFun function is called, it takes the value of _A after the loop finished and not the value at which setInterval was set.

**Question**

So the question is, **how can i pass a unique index into the setInterval callback**, so the callback knows which array item to use?

**Final solution**

If anyone is interested, the final solution: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvy6q/1/)**

Comment: create a convenience/wrapper around setInterval eg. _setMyCallbackInterval_ and have that call setInterval as appropriate

Comment: please provide jsfiddle if possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most direct way to solve it is using closures.
Try something like this:

```
for(_A=0; _A < things_to_move.length; _A++) {
    setInterval((function(_innerA){
        return function(){ showFun(_innerA); };
    })(_A), things_to_move[_A][1]);
}
```

Comment: Consider pulling the closure out of the `setInterval` and instead pass in `_innerA` as a param to `setInterval`. I think it would be a little bit cleaner.